# Sync and dedupe contacts?

Tags: android, windows-phone, iphone-app, contact-manager

I am a smartphone fan, I have used Windows Phone, iPhones, Androids and many more devices.

Each platform requires different accounts, for instance Microsoft requires a Hotmail account, while Android requires Gmail etc.

Over the past few years what I started to notice is, my contacts are being duplicated and some of the Hotmail contacts don't exist in my Gmail account and vice versa. It became a nightmare.

I am looking for some tools that will help me manage/sync my contacts and make sure they are not duplicated.

It could be an app or an application for Mac or Windows, I dont really mind.

Comment: So a solution has to sync the contacts with *all* your devices (running Android, iOS, and Windows Phone)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can recommend [em Client](http://www.emclient.com/), which is free and has a built-in deduplicator.

Comment: cool ! I just wish this was free :(

Comment: It is free. You can request a free license from the app itself.

Comment: [link to free license request](http://www.emclient.com/free-license) @AlPacino

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Lot of potential in this answer but please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality and add screenshots and usage experience for instance, thanks!